# Use hardcoded list of values in query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a list of ISO2 country codes I want to use in a query.
Something like this:

```
select cou, 128,13, 1
from ('AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', [snip]) as cou
```

But.. working.

I remember doing such a thing in the past, but I can't find any doc about it anymore.
It's a one shot query so I don't mind performance, coding practice or maintainability.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
As Pax noted, it is indeed better practice to have this data in my database for all the good reasons. I understand his opinion because I would answer the same. However, this data already IS in another table, in another database, on another server, on another network..

In order to test my queries I need some quick shot values in a table on this new database. I don't want to configure networks, cross-server queries etc just to test my queries on some real-life data. I hope this explains why I go against the stream for this one shot.

Comment: I like how ,despite my disclaimer, people still suggest I should put it in a table. Don't get me wrong. I would do the same :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First way using union:

```
select 'AD' union all select 'AE' ....
```

The second - not obvious, but elegant - using recursive queries;

```
declare @x as varchar(200)
set @x = 'ADAEAFAGAIALAM'
;with FakeTbl AS (
    SELECT substring(@x, 1, 2) sval, 0 as ROWN
        WHERE LEN(@x) > 0 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT substring(@x, (it.ROWN+1)*2+1, 2) sval, it.ROWN+1 as ROWN
        FROM FakeTbl it
        WHERE LEN(@x) > (it.ROWN+1)*2
)
select sval, ROWN from FakeTbl
```

You places to @x string, assuming that code has len 2. Small restriction of this method is recursive level (for 2005 it is 100)

Comment: You can remove the default recursion limit by adding OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) to the end of your query

Comment: We appear to have differing definitions of the word "elegant" :-)

Comment: @Pax - this sample is taken from real code. We just created table-value function - that accepts varchar string  (so instead of @x used input argument). And it works in multiple use cases.

Comment: @Dewfy, don't take offense, I really do marvel the ingenuity but appall its performance, understandability and maintainability. Just my own very subjective reasoning off course.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to offend. The definition I most associate with elegant is "unusually effective and simple". Your solution is effective but hardly simple. Still, it *is* clever and that itself can sometimes be a good thing.

Comment: @Pax, it's ok, that is why I've provided the first way.

Answer (score 35):

Values keyword can be used to achieve this.

```
select col1, 128 col2, 13 col3, 1 col4
from ( values ('AD'), ('AE'), ('AF'), ('AG'), ('AI'), ('AL'), ('AM')) as x (col1)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer, whatever your understanding of elegance. To join, `SELECT * FROM RealTable INNER JOIN ( VALUES ('one value'), ('another_val')) AS x (col) ON RealCol=col`. To join creating a cartesian, `SELECT * FROM RealTable INNER JOIN ( VALUES ('one value'), ('another_val')) AS x (col) ON 1=1`

Answer (score 6):

Pax's answer is correct approach. But if you insist on doing it in-line:

```
select cou, 128,13, 1
from (select 'AD' as cou
      union all select 'AE'
      union all select  'AF'
      union all select  'AG'
      union all select  'AI'
      union all select  'AL'
      union all select  'AM') as X
```

Answer (score 4):

The *best* way to do this (despite your desire to have them hard-coded) is to create a table of country codes:

```
create table iso2_codes (
    code char(2) primary key
)
insert into iso2_codes (code) vales ('AD');
insert into iso2_codes (code) vales ('AE');
: : :
insert into iso2_codes (code) vales ('AM');
```

Then just use

```
select code, 128, 13, 1 from iso2_codes;
```

I am of the firm belief that data should be stored in tables where it can be easily changed, not embedded within source code or scripts where it's a nightmare to track down and modify.

That's my opinion, others may disagree.

Comment: +1. Even though the other answers give you a solution to what you ask, you should stop and think about what it will cost you maintaining it.

Comment: The problem is that the data IS in another database and needs to be put in this table on another server. It would be MUCh more work to configure the network, connections, rights and cross-server queries then just select them and insert them through this list.

Comment: I added some info in the OP with this regard

Comment: This (or rather, a temp table), is the correct way to do it.